# GStreamer - swap color channels of RGB-video

Tags: gstreamer, color-channel

I am new to GStreamer and I try to swap the color channels of a RGB-video. (e.g. red to blue). How can I do this with gst-launch?

I go trough this list but I am unable to find an element to do it: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html

Comment: not sure if this is doable in gst-launch, certainly doable programmatically.. you can change some colors with `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! coloreffects preset=yellowblue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink` .. but its not what you want - but its fun

Comment: maybe you can trick videoconvert with fault caps to make it think its in for example BGRA format but real format would be RGBA .. but I dont know if you can do it - and its just a hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote now my own Element. I used "Colorflip" as my base Element, changed the name to "ChannelFlip" (you must rename all methods from gst_video_flip_bla to gst_channel_flip_bla and rename the structs).
Then I was able to register my element with:

`gst_element_register(NULL, "channelflip", GST_RANK_NONE, GST_TYPE_CHANNEL_FLIP);`

Then I added my enums to `GstChannelFlipMethod` and my properties to `_GstChannelFlip`. Changed caps to "RGB" and added my Code to `gst_channel_flip_packed_simple` and called it in `gst_channel_flip_transform_frame` instead of `videoflip->process (videoflip, out_frame, in_frame);` with:

```
GST_OBJECT_LOCK (videoflip);
    //videoflip->process (videoflip, out_frame, in_frame);
    gst_channel_flip_packed_simple(videoflip, out_frame, in_frame);
GST_OBJECT_UNLOCK (videoflip);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually trick GStreamer by replacing the caps:

> gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, format=RGBx ! capssetter replace=true caps="video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive" ! videoconvert ! ximagesink

Please note that:

> "width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive"

are the default settings for `videotestsrc`. If you, for example, want another resolution, you need to declare it twice:

> gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, format=RGBx, width=640, height=480 ! capssetter replace=true caps="video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive" ! videoconvert ! ximagesink

But of course having a dedicated element is the better solution in order to support proper dynamic caps negotiation.

Comment: I've got similar task with audiostream -- to swap byte order of pcm data with improper caps. And `capssetter` does the trick. However alternative solution I found was to use `rawaudioparse`. So maybe `rawvideoparse` could help in op's case.

Comment: Another option is to use `...video/x-raw,format=BGR ! multipartmux ! multipartdemux single-stream=1 ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! ....' it allows just changing the format while preserving other caps properties.